# Position of adverb "now"

Tags: adverbs

> 1. There is no school in Japan **now** that doesn't have a computer.
> 2. There is no school in Japan that **now** doesn't have a computer.
> 3. There is no school in Japan that doesn't have a computer **now**.

Which position is suitable for the adverb "now"?

Comment: Now, There isn't a school in Japan that doesn't have a computer now.

Answer (score 2):

All three of your sentences are understandable and acceptable.
It is merely a question of style expression.

Comment: And I'd say that "now" is not needed, unless you are contrasting with some past condition.